# Change timezone in Russia 26.10.14 in mac os x 10.9.5

Tags: macos

Maybe somebody know. How you know, 26.10.14 in Russia will change the time-zones. My mac os x (10.9.5) will automatically change time to new time-zone ? How can i check this?

Comment: You mean the summer-winter time change ?

Comment: No. Russia will permanently switch to winter time on 26 October. http://www.bbc.com/news/blogs-news-from-elsewhere-28423647

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check your system to change the time zone , you can run this command in terminal:

```
zdump -v /etc/localtime | grep 2014
```

If you see two lines:

```
/etc/localtime  Sat Oct 25 21:59:59 2014 UTC = Sun Oct 26 01:59:59 2014 MSK isdst=0
/etc/localtime  Sat Oct 25 22:00:00 2014 UTC = Sun Oct 26 01:00:00 2014 MSK isdst=0
```

Time zone will be changed automatically.

- You can manually update time zones:
  You can find time preferences on the Mac OS on the two files: /etc/localtime and /usr/share/icu/icudtXXX.dat.

Settings for console time are stored on the /etc/localtime.

For other programms - on the /usr/share/icu/icudtXXX.dat

Update /etc/localtime:

```
download last tzdata on the [iana][1]
extract: tar xzf ./tzdata2011l.tar.gz
apply: sudo zic europe
check: zdump -v /etc/localtime | grep 2014
```

If all ok, you see something like this:

```
/etc/localtime  Sat Oct 25 21:59:59 2014 UTC = Sun Oct 26 01:59:59 2014 MSK isdst=0
/etc/localtime  Sat Oct 25 22:00:00 2014 UTC = Sun Oct 26 01:00:00 2014 MSK isdst=0
```

Update /usr/share/icu/icudtXXX.dat - you can compile icudtXXX.dat or download it.

Compile:

```
Download [source][2]
Extract: `tar xzf ICU-400.42.tar.gz && cd ICU-400.42/icuSources`
Copy actual tzdata to the sources: `cp ~/tzdata2011l.tar.gz ./tools/tzcode/`
compile: `./runConfigureICU MacOSX --with-data-packaging=archive && gmake`
Backup origin tzdata: `cp /usr/share/icu/icudt40l.dat ~`
Install new: `sudo install -o root -g wheel -m 0644 -Sp data/out/icudt40l.dat /usr/share/icu/icudt40l.dat`
reboot
```

Comment: +10, for having a Terminal command for everything :)

Answer (score 0):

If your settings in the syst pref for date and time are set to:

Time Zone- Russia/Moscow

[image: zone]

And you set the Set time using the Apple Europe server, then it will do it automatically.

[image: time]

So it gets its date/time from the server- following what ever Mr. Putin has decided.
Just to compare when I made the above screen shots it was Wed. Oc. 15 at 1:25 (after midnight here in USA-Pacific time.

Comment: Wrong. NTP server (including apple's time.whatever.apple.com) would only provide you with precise UTC/GMT time; your local time is then calculated depending on the settings of your timezone (see /etc/localtime and /usr/share/zoneinfo - there is IANA Timezone Database that gets updated when timezones shift due to legislation or whatever). Now, these timezone definitions are usually updated with the OS X updates/hotfixes. Luckily, 10.9.5 will adjust your clock to 1:00 AM the second after Sun Oct 26 01:59:59 2014 MSK

Comment: @kervich I did not know that, thanks for clarifying.